# OpenCv, decompose and re-compose a projection matrix

Tags: opencv

I have an opencv computer vision application.

I am trying to decompose a camera projection matrix, then I will adjust the tvec and rvec, and re-compose it into a new projection matrix.

To get this up an running, I am first trying to decompose the matrix, then rebuild it as it was, and compare the result.

I am loading the Matrix from an xml with:

```
cv::FileStorage fs("calibStereo.xml", cv::FileStorage::READ);

    fs["P1"] >> P1;
```

I then decompose the matrix with:

```
cv::Mat Kd(3, 3, cv::DataType<float>::type); // intrinsic parameter matrix
cv::Mat Rd(3, 3, cv::DataType<float>::type); // rotation matrix
cv::Mat Td(4, 1, cv::DataType<float>::type); // translation vector
cv::Mat newP1(4, 3, cv::DataType<float>::type); 

cv::decomposeProjectionMatrix(P1, Kd, Rd, Td);
```

This works fine.

I then have the following function (from the cv::sfm module)

```
template<typename T>
void
projectionFromMatrices(const cv::Mat_<T> &K, const cv::Mat_<T> &R, const cv::Mat_<T> &t, cv::Mat_<T> P)
{
    hconcat(K*R, K*t, P);
}

void MatrixFunctions::projectionFromKRt(cv::Mat _K, cv::Mat _R, cv::Mat _t, cv::Mat &_P)
{
    const cv::Mat K = _K, R = _R, t = _t;
    const int depth = K.depth();
    CV_Assert((K.cols == 3 && K.rows == 3) && (t.cols == 1 && t.rows == 3) && (K.size() == R.size()));
    CV_Assert((depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_64F) && depth == R.depth() && depth == t.depth());

    _P.create(3, 4, depth);

    cv::Mat P = _P;

    // type
    if (depth == CV_32F)
    {
        projectionFromMatrices<float>(K, R, t, P);
    }
    else
    {
        projectionFromMatrices<double>(K, R, t, P);
    }

}
```

This takes a 3x1 translation vector, and decomposeProjectionMatrix returns a 4x1.

So I add:

```
cv::Mat T(3, 1, cv::DataType<float>::type); // new translation vector
cv::convertPointsFromHomogeneous(Td, T);

MatFunc->projectionFromKRt(Kd, Rd, T, newP1);
```

This gives me an `assertion failed` in the `convertPointsFromHomogeneous` function.

Where am i going wrong here?

Comment: I have solved this by using this function instead:

`https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/sfm/src/projection.cpp#L58`

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `Td` into a 4 channels 1x1 matrix.

```
cv::convertPointsFromHomogeneous(Td.reshape(4), T);
```

Then you may need to convert `T` into a 1 channel 3x1 matrix:

```
T = T.reshape(1).t();
```

Note that `T` is the camera position in the world basis.
You may want to use `-Rd*T` as the translation.